# 2000 ford ranger won't start

Tags: ford, starting, ranger, ignition-key

I have a 2000 Ford Ranger. I thought I lost my keys and ended up destroying my pat system, then I found my keys but now I can't get it to start. what are my options?

Comment: how did you destroy the pats system? you may be able to find a transponder bypass module or similar, like whats used in aftermarket remote start systems.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like once the Ford PAT system has tripped, it needs a dealer to fix it...